# MongoDB document update operation cannot be compiled

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Checked many times. The code looks fine to me, but the compiler constantly fails to compile. Can anyone see the problems?

I am trying to add a feedback object of a specific teacher to his/her own feebacks array.

document structure:

```
{
  studentName: 'xxx',
  teachers: [
    {
      teacherName: 'xxx',
      feedbacks: []
    }
  ]
}
```

```
await collection.updateOne({
                studentName: req.body.name,
                teachers: {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        teacherName: {
                            $eq: 'xxx'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                $push: {
                    teachers.$.feedbacks: req.body
                }
            });
```

[image: result]

Comment: `teachers.$.feedbacks` need to be in single quote/double quote `"teachers.$.feedbacks"`

Comment: ontop of the syntax error, this is very bad design. You can save the feedback in a separate collection and populate them. This allows you to update and query in a cleaner manner in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use double quotes to avoid the syntax error.

You have to think you are programming in node.js and the object will be read by Mongo. But is created using node syntaxis.

So, you can create an object whose key are simply letters without double quotes, but to create a key with `$` or `.` you need to do with `" "`.

So you need to do: `'teachers.$.feedbacks': req.body`